# Why do char{} and char() work as a temporary variable for a char* argument?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, visual-c++-2017

In Visual C++ 2017 (with `/std:c++14` or with `/std:c++17`), the following code works:

```
void TakePtr(char*); // const or not

int main()
{ 
     TakePtr(char{});
     TakePtr(char());
}
```

I don't understand why it works.

Apparently, the following would also work (as expected):

```
void TakeChar(char);

   TakeChar(char{});
   TakeChar(char());
```

How does the compiler deduce (or convert) the type `char` to `char*`, when `char{}` or `char()` is used as an argument?

Now, if I have both `char` and `char*` overloads, it works without any error/warning about ambiguity:

```
void TakePtr(char*);
void TakePtr(char);

    TakePtr(char{});  // Chooses 'char'
    TakePtr(char());  // Chooses 'char'
```

Why is the compiler okay with `char{}` for `TakePtr(char*)`?
And why doesn't it give a warning/error when choosing the *better* version? Such behavior is bound to break existing code.

For sure, the compiler isn't happy with:

```
void TakePtr(char*);

    char c{};
    TakePtr(c);
```

Comment: A wild guess: `char()` constructs a temporary `(char)0` which is convertible to any integral `0` which is accepted as null pointer. I tested in godbolt, and I believe I'm right: [**Compiler Explorer**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MzDXz_).

Comment: @Scheff, `xor ecx, ecx; call void TakePtr(char *)`.

Comment: @Evg Yepp. That's why I believe I'm right. ;-)

Comment: Might be able to squelch the undesirable behavior by adding `void TakePtr(char) = delete;`

Comment: @Scheff, Bang on! `TakePtr(char{8})` fails, `TakePtr(char{0})` doesn't.

Comment: @Eljay, When another overload is present (`TakePtr(char`) or made *not-present* by explicit `delete`, it raises an error. When only one (`char*`) is present it takes it.

Comment: Ugh, that is very annoying.  I no longer work at Microsoft on Visual Studio, so I am no longer in a position to investigate the problem.  For what its worth, clang emits an error.

Comment: FWIW, VS2017 and above now has a [conformance mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=vs-2019) you can turn on to make it more standard compliant.  It doesn't help in this case though :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply MSVC being behind: the rule in C++03 was that *any* constant expression of integer type and value 0 was a null pointer constant and could thus be converted to `char*`.  Certainly `char()` qualifies—and `char{}` means the same thing, although it never overlapped with the rule.

Answer (score 13):

Because Visual lies a lot. Especially older one. Your code prompts clang to report an error:

```
<source>:9:6: error: no matching function for call to 'TakePtr'

     TakePtr(char{});

     ^~~~~~~

<source>:5:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to 'char *' for 1st argument

void TakePtr(char*); // const or not

     ^

<source>:10:6: error: no matching function for call to 'TakePtr'

     TakePtr(char());

     ^~~~~~~

<source>:5:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char' to 'char *' for 1st argument

void TakePtr(char*); // const or not

     ^

2 errors generated.
```

Visual is known to be "wonky" in term of following C++ standard, so don't rely on it too much. Try to verify with clang / gcc, just to be sure.